# Combinatorial Probability (hypergeometric distribution)

Tags: probability, combinations

A question bank has $40$ questions, out of which $5$ are from the subject International Relations. A computer can only take $30$ of the questions for a test paper. Taken randomly, what is the probability that at least one of the questions is from the subject International Relations.

I did this question and got very high probability of $0.99967..$

Is this correct? I am feeling I may have missed something here.

Comment: How did you get that result? Please include your work.

Comment: Looks right, except for possible typo: $P\approx 0.999617$

Comment: 1-(Probability(no IR question is selected): 35 C 30 / 40 C 30) = Probability that at least 1 IR question is selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event that at least $1$ question is from the subject International Relations is complementary to the event that *none* of the questions is from this subject. So
$$1-\frac{\dbinom{35}{30}\dbinom{5}{0}}{\dbinom{40}{30}}=1-0.000382974\approx 0.999617$$
(The fraction is the probability that $X=0$, where $X$ follows hypergeometric distribution with parameters $N=40$ (population size), $n=30$ (sample size) and $k=5$ (successes in the population).

Comment: thank you so much. That was very precise explanation.